# Windows service using BackgroundService cannot be stopped

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, .net-core-3.0, background-service

I'm using a Net Core 3.X BackgroundService and after publishing my code, I've installed the executable generated as a Windows Service.

On my ExecuteAsync method I have some code like this:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //do something

        if(someConditionIsTrue)
        {
            await this.StopAsync(new CancellationToken());
        }
    }
}
```

That manual call on StopAsync stops the execution and exits from while loop, but when I go to services.msc I see that my Windows Service is still in running state although is not executing anything.

How can I stop the service automatically and not calling to "cmd \c sc stop..."?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BackgroundService` is stopping correctly, but the *application* is not being stopped.

To stop the application *from* a background service, inject a `IHostApplicationLifetime` and call it as such:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    //do something

    if (someConditionIsTrue)
    {
      _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
    }
  }
}
```

You don't need to call `this.StopAsync` because that will (eventually) be called by `StopApplication`.